# Lambda - Converting output in forloop to a dic to allow for single email rather than multiple

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am struggling to convert this captured output as a dictionary so i can distribute the list of users who have a password over 90 days old:

```
import boto3
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::9999999999:role/role",
    RoleSessionName="AssumedRoleSession2"
)
credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']
resource=boto3.resource(
    'iam',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
)
sns = boto3.client('sns')
import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(context,event):
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    for user in resource.users.all():
        if user.password_last_used is not None:
            delta = (today - user.password_last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
            if delta >= 90:
                print(','.join(('Username: ',str([user.user_name]), str(delta))))
                sns_message = ','.join(('Username: ',str([user.user_name]), str(delta)))
            response = sns.publish(
            TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:1111111111:topic',
                Message= sns_message,
                Subject='Users who have failed to log in over 90 Days',
            )
```

My current attempt is causing 189 emails containing a single user name and password age, i want an email contenting a list of users and their password ages

Is there anyone kind enough to help me?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: You can make a list of users strings, then join it with \n and send message after for loop.

Comment: Also, why just not use f-strings, format or % instead of ','.join() construction, will be faster and easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Fominykh Maxim
I have attempted to capture the users as a list of strings but i am struggling now to get the lambda to work.  I think i need. break from looking at it.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your sns.publish is inside your for loop. Create your list of users inside the loop then call the publish command.
I may get some of the syntax wrong as i can't test, but hopefully you'll the point.

```
user_list = []
for user in resource.users.all():
    if user.password_last_used is not None:
        delta = (today - user.password_last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
        if delta >= 90:
            print(','.join(('Username: ',str([user.user_name]), str(delta))))
            user_list.append(','.join(('Username: ',str([user.user_name]), str(delta))))

sns_message = user_list # you may need to check formatting of this prior to sending to sns???? it's a list, not a string
response = sns.publish(
TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:1111111111:topic',
    Message= sns_message,
    Subject='Users who have failed to log in over 90 Days',
)
```